# Can't work with object after sending it via Ajax request

Tags: ajax, laravel, bootstrap-modal

I sent to my bootstrap modal this content with Ajax:

```
<div class="list-of-players text-center">
    <div class="list">
        @foreach($team->players as $player)
            <a class="player_choose" id="player_id_Standard_{{$player->id}}">
                <div class="player">
                    <span class="p_name"><span class="flag-icon {{$player->nationality->flag}}"></span> {{$player->fullname}}</span>
                </div>
            </a>
        @endforeach
    </div>
</div>
```

But then when I want to choose some element of this modal window by this code:

```
$('.player_choose').click(function () {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```

It doesn't work. What can be a problem? Maybe js don't see "player_choose" elements after ajax?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Your script executes before you get this element with ajax. You should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). This should work:

```
$(document).on('click','.player_choose', function () {
    $('.modal').modal('hide');
});
```